# How to read Autocorrelations in GLS models?

Tags: autocorrelation, autoregressive, generalized-least-squares

I am playing with some marketing data. My response variable is `market share` and predictors are `time, brand, retail price, marketing activity`.

`brand` is categorical, but would be a random factor. `retail price` is numerical and `marketing activity` is binary. 1 indicates activity and 0 indicates no activity.

The question that I am trying to answer is the influence of `retail price` and `activity` on `market share` for specific `brands`.

As usual, started off with a simple linear model and the residual plot quickly showed autocorrelation and so did `acf` and `pacf`.[image]

I tried `gls` model in R:

```
# Generalized least square
nav_gls <- gls(market_share~display_indicator*retail_price_avg*week_number, data=market_share_df)
nav_gls_corr <- update(nav_gls, correlation=corAR1())
AIC(nav_gls, nav_gls_corr)
```

The results don't improve.

```
        df       AIC
nav_gls       9 -2373.980
nav_gls_corr 10 -2604.405
```

Shouldn't my AIC improve by considering even a single period AR? Also, how do you account for autocorrelation when the lag period is more than 1. What is the intuition for using a lag period more than 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A decrease in AIC corresponds to an improvement in the model fit. Based on your results the model with an AR(1) component has improved over the one without, since for the AR(1) fit the AIC is smaller.

I suggest that you look into *distributed lag models* (aka *transfer function models*) since those are specifically designed for problems with input-output relationships, such as yours. Your output is the *market share* while inputs are the rest of the variables (predictors). Before putting the variables into a distributed lag model you should first identify the relationship of each input (predictor) with the output (*market share*). Since you are dealing with time series, a simple scatter plot will not suffice for that purpose, since the relationships between time series (e.g. between *market share* and *retail price*) can be distributed over time instead of being contemporaneous. Cross correlation functions (ccf, which can be obtrained from the R *tseries* package) can be of great help when appropriately used.

For more information on how to build distributed lag models and study input-output relationships, you may find the following two articles helpful (they provide a hands-on  guidance on how to build those models):

*Bisgaard, S., & Kulahci, M. (2006). Quality Quandaries: Studying input-output relationships, part I. Quality Engineering, 18(2), 273-281.*

*Bisgaard, S. R., & Kulahci, M. (2006). Quality Quandaries: Studying Input-Output Relationships, Part II. Quality Engineering, 18(3), 405-410.*

Comment: Will look into it. Thank you.